# Rails: Find the ID of a record after using exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Using two different models, `RecordLabel` and `Artist`, I want to link to their pages if the record is found using their usernames. I have no problems finding if the record exists, but I can't figure out how to find the ID of that record. What I have:

```
<% if RecordLabel.exists?(:username => "#{@artist.artist_profile.record_label_name}") %>
  <%= link_to @artist.artist_profile.record_label_name, record_label_path(RecordLabel.find(### NEED RECORD LABEL ID ###) %>
<% else %>
  <%= @artist.artist_profile.record_label_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please share your controller, models and schema so that we can see it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the record very easily this way (if it exists):

```
RecordLabel.where(:username => "#{@artist.artist_profile.record_label_name}").first
```

So, your code becomes:

```
<% if RecordLabel.exists?(:username => "#{@artist.artist_profile.record_label_name}") %>
<%= link_to @artist.artist_profile.record_label_name,
            record_label_path(RecordLabel.where(:username => "#{@artist.artist_profile.record_label_name}").first) %>
<% else %>
  <%= @artist.artist_profile.record_label_name %>
<% end %>
```

This should work and solve your problem.